# Get substring, cast it to int, increment it and concat it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
select 
    CONCAT('~', (cast (ISNULL((select substring(max(NR), 2, len(max(NR)) - 1)   
                               from XY 
                               where left(NR, 1) = '~'), 0) AS int) + 1))
```

What this should achieve is getting the max number of the column **NR** which is prepended with a `~`.

This seems to work fine for numbers up to 10. But once I have an entry in XY where NR is **~10** it always returns the same result and I can't seem to figure out why. So here is the breakdown of the statement in my opinion:

From inner to outer:

First i get the substring in the length of the maximum number which is prepended with a tilde (solely the number) of **NR** starting at position 2 in order to ignore the tilde.

Then I increment the number and handle it as a string.

Finally I prepend a tilde and concat it which should. This should achieve the desired output in my opinion.

Table XY:

| ID | NR |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | ~1 |
| 12 | ~2 |
| 13 | ~3 |
| 14 | ~4 |
| 15 | ~5 |
| 16 | ~6 |
| 17 | ~7 |
| 18 | ~8 |
| 17 | ~9 |
| 18 | ~10 |

Desired output for Select statement with above table:

**~11**

Actual output:

**~10**

TLDR; if there are entries in NR prepended with a tilde (i can assure that always an integer trails after the tilde):

I want the select statement to return the max number of NR which is prepended with a tilde +1

If there are no entries with a tilde in NR -> return **~1**

Comment: It's usually better to store the *individual elements* using appropriate date types and leave constructing a formatted string to a computed column (or your presentation layer) rather than storing a formatted value and then having to *undo* the formatting in order to work with the elements again.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes its definitely a design flaw. But the business logic requires a temporary name to the entity which is presented to the user. This solution results in less effort at GUI-side. At least in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, `NR` is a string.  Although you are casting to an `int`, it would seem something is going wrong.  I would suggest simplifying the query to something like this:

```
select concat('~',
              coalesce(max(cast(stuff(nr, 1, 1, '') as int)) + 1, 1)
             ), stuff(max(nr), 1, 1, ''), max(nr)
from XY
where nr like '~%';
```

Note that storing an integer encoded in a string is usually a bad idea.  Why not just store an integer, using an `identity()` column or a sequence.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e290febdccf356d6605a4babc28c894c) is a db<>fiddle.